# Is it possible to generate a word document in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to be able to transform a payload and generate a word document. Can this be done in any of the WSO2 products?

Comment: As docx is xml, I guess this should be possible using WSO2 EI, read the file and parse the /w:document/w:body element. But I think much depends on the input and what you want to do.

Comment: I want to expose a rest service in WSO2 ESB that accepts a JSON payload, generate a docx file by exporting that incoming payload to a word document and save it in the registry or the file system.

Comment: I'd use a custom mediator for that. It's not hard and gives you a lot of freedom to implement the transformation. However, I don't think the ESB is the right place to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Generating a word document requires logic which is not a single or simple transformation. WSO2EI out of box provide simple transformations such as to text, xml, json or byte stream. So no, you cannot simply generate a word document with any build-in functionality.

As a solution - docx documents are ZIP files with some resources, including the content itself. You may implement the document generation using some framework (Jasper, Apache POI, ...)  or you can do it yourself generating the doc from XML content, example:

- [Using XSLT and Open XML to Create a Word 2007 Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/ee872374(v=office.12))
- [Creating Word reports with XSL transformations](https://dradisframework.com/support/guides/reporting/xslt_reports.html)